# Spring data redis always returns the same results

Tags: java, spring, redis, spring-data, spring-data-redis

I'm querying Redis using Spring Data Redis and JPA-style query methods:

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
   User findByUsernameAndPassword(String username, String password);
}
```

This method returns the user perfectly, but once I created a second user, I realised that once this method is invoked once, it keeps returning the same result, regardless of the values of the parameters.

I haven't enabled any cache, and even so, that should be based on the parameters.

The entity User:

```
@RedisHash("users")
public class User {
    private @Id Long id;
    private @Indexed String username;
    private @Indexed String password;
    private UserRole role;

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public UserRole getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(UserRole role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Is it a known issue in Spring Data Redis? Am I doing anthing wrong?

Dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-redis</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
```

I forced using the latest version of Spring data redis so I could get the new `@RedisHash` and `@TimeToLive` annotations

**EDIT**

Example case:

```
    User userA = new User();
    userA.setUsername("admin");
    userA.setPassword("admin");
    userA.setRole(UserRole.ADMIN);

    userRepository.save(userA);

    User userB = new User();
    userB.setUsername("aaa");
    userB.setPassword("aaa");

    userRepository.save(userB);

    userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword("aaa","aaa"); //Returns user B (aaa,aaa)
    userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword("admin","admin"); //Returns user B again, instead of A        
    userRepository.findByUsernameAndPassword("222","222"); //Returns user B again again! even though it doesn't exist.
```

If we get users by Id, everything works fine

Comment: Your code looks fine. Could you post a reproducible test case?

Comment: I added an example case

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem. would you please open an issue in [Jira](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS).

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing in my project.  I'm using "monitor" to watch the commands that are sent to redis.  It always sends the same command to redis even when the value changes.

Comment: created https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-546